# Cannot mark second disk in raid1 array as active

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have two 3TB drives, with a single ext4 partition on each.

I have added both drives to my raid1 array but running

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

outputs:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 27 09:57:07 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930134016 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 1
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Dec 28 00:15:06 2016
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

           Name : i3:0  (local to host i3)
           UUID : fd445401:e6153885:3b3e1a44:7f4e953d
         Events : 32

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        -      spare   /dev/sdc1
```

Can anyone tell me why `/dev/sdc1` is marked as spare and not active and no sync has occurred?

Thanks in advance.

As requested, `cat /proc/mdstat` outputs:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1](S)
      2930134016 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sdb` outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 81404E26-1A56-409F-9F50-B1BBDF405740

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Linux filesystem
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sdc` outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 81404E26-1A56-409F-9F50-B1BBDF405740

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Linux filesystem
```

Looking at these outputs obviously the UUID's are, well, duplicated, so I assume if I make them unique I might then be able to resolve the second device not being active.

However, using tune2fs I cannot set the UUID. No errors but `sudo lsblk -fo UUID /dev/sdc1` outputs the original UUID.

Comment: Your output is garbled, making it hard to read.  Can you please also include the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`, as well as `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`.  It's at the very least weird that you are adding ext4 partitions to an mdraid version 1.2 array.

Comment: So what type should they be added as? I'll get the other outputs now.

TIA

Comment: Looking at these outputs obviously the UUID's are, well, duplicated, so I assume if I make them unique I might then be able to get the second device as active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so I did this:

- removing the second device from the array
- removing the superblock from the partition
- fixing the non-unique disk UUID
- re-adding the disk

... it has now started rebuilding the array.  :)